1С-Битрикс не отображаются настройки компонентов
В комплексных компонентах не отображаются настройки компонентов кроме как выбор шаблона и выглядит это так

В настройки параметров обычных компонентов я вообще не могу зайти в верхнем углу появляется бесконечная загрузка а от сервера приходит 500 ошибка

Что это может быть? С правами все в порядке
